# RxJava merge параллельное выполнение

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, rxandroid, rxjava2

Не удается запустить параллельно два Observable через merge.

```
class MyExample {

    //Создание observable
    public static Observable<String> createObservable(String name){
        return Observable.create(o -> {
            Integer count = 1;
            while (count++ < 100) {
                Thread.sleep(100);//TODO:Имитация работы удаленного сервера
                o.onNext(name+"_"+count.toString());
            }
            o.onComplete();
        });
    }

    public MyExample() {            
        //Формируем список из observable
        List<Observable<String>> ol = new ArrayList<>();
        ol.add(createObservable("Первый"));
        ol.add(createObservable("Второй"));

        Observable<String> rxObservable = Observable.merge(ol)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

        //Слушатель, выводит в консоль все что ему присылают
        DisposableObserver<String> observer = new DisposableObserver<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onNext(String s) {
                Log.e("rx", s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Log.e("rx", "error");
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                Log.e("rx", "complete");
            }
        };

        rxObservable.subscribe(observer); //Запускаем
    }

}
```

При выполнении, в консоли строки `Первый_x` и `Второй_x` должны появляться вперемешку, так описана работа `.megre()`. Но почему то, выполнение происходит последовательно, и сначала появляются все `Первый_x` и только потом все  `Второй_x`. В чем проблема?

Comment: попробуйте `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` добавить в `createObservable` к каждому observable отдельно

Comment: @zRrr, работает. Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выяснилось что `subscribeOn()` для `merge()`, сообщает в каком потоке будет выполняться подписка на указанные `Observables`.
А что бы задать в каком потоке они должны выполняться, надо для каждого `Observable`, отдельно вызвать `subscribeOn()`.

Ответ нашел [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40390004/rxjava-merge-subscriber-gets-results-only-from-first-observable/40390229#40390229), и в комментарии @zRrr.